# How to convert rows' values into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
  ID      Location       Value        Count
  1              X           6           13
  1              X           5           10
```

I want to convert two value in rows value into column name with the corresponding count like:

```
  ID      Location           6            5 
  1              X          13           10
```

Comment: what is the shape of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(values=['Count'], index=['ID', 'Location'], columns=['Value'])
```

**Output**

```
            Count
Value           5   6
ID Location
1  X           10  13
```

You can [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to bring it to the OP's expected output shape -

```
df1.reset_index()

      ID Location Count
Value                 5   6
0      1        X    10  13
```